# Run function in series with dynamic arguments in nodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, synchronization, cheerio

Goal: (solved: updated working code below)

1. Create an array of urls
2. Create a function that accepts a single url, makes a request to that url, and writes some data to file
3. Run above function in series multiple times for each url in the array.

Node Dependencies: Request, Cheerio, async, fs

Here is what I have so far:

```
//load dependencies
var request = require("request"),
    cheerio = require("cheerio"),
    fs = require('fs'),
    async = require('async'),
    wstream = fs.createWriteStream('./model/data.txt');


//create url array
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    arr.push('http://www.test.com/' + i)
}

//function that gets data from url and creates write stream
function getUrlData(url, callback){
    request(url, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var $ = cheerio.load(body);
            var data = $('h1').html();
            wstream.write(data);
            callback();
        }
    });
}

//close write stream
function endStream(){
    wstream.end();
}

//updated working version
async.eachSeries(arr,getUrlData,endStream);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want getUrlData to be executed sequentually, you'll need to add a callback to getUrlData:

```
function getUrlData(url, callback){
    request(url, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var $ = cheerio.load(body);
            var data = $('h1').html();
            wstream.write(data);
            callback();
        }
        callback(error);
    });
}
```

Then use eachSeries:

```
async.eachSeries(arr, getUrlData, endStream);
```